# generics in constructors in Java?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, bounded-wildcard

Consider this hypothetical class (which I found in a online video):

```
public class Contrived<T extends Number> extends ArrayList<T> {
      List <? extends T> values;
      ......
    }
```

Here the type variables that `Contrived` can accept is `Number` or some sub-type of `Number`. But the class itself inherits from `ArrayList`, so what-ever type the class gets, will determine the type of `ArrayList`.

Now there is a field called `values`, which is `List<? extends T values>`. so what does this mean here?
Does the `list` can hold anything that extends `T` (which in turn extend `Number`).

by `PECS (producer extends, consumer super)` rule, can I only use this `List` to read elements but not add to the `list`.

how will the `constructor` look like, if I need to pass a `list of doubles or some type T`?

Comment: I don't think I fully got the idea behind the `Contrived` class. What is it supposed to do? It extends `ArrayList`, and has a list `values` as a reference variable. The class thus basically contains two lists, what's the intention of the class? A useful constructor depends on that (e.g. "What should the constructor do?"). Can you link to the source?

Comment: @dst: it is a hypothetical class. nothing important it is doing as such. but I am wondering how a constructor for it will look it like and what operations can be done the given `list` field?

Comment: `public Contrived(List<T> list)` ?

Comment: @HighCore @user1988876 or `public Contrived(List<? extends T> list)`? Or do you want a method body?

Comment: @HighCore: shouldn't constructor be `public Contrived(List<? extends T> list)`

Comment: You can only assign something to the list so that's all the constructor can do. I don't totally understand what the question is here. If the class is hypothetical, how would we know what it's supposed to do?

Comment: @user1988876 it depends on which list you wish to fill (the array list or the instance variable), or if you wish to do something completely different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a constructor that takes a `List<T>` or a `List<? extends T>`.  Continuing to contrive classes:

```
class B extends Number{
   public double doubleValue() { return 0; }
   public float floatValue() { return 0; }
   public long longValue() { return 0; }
   public int intValue() { return 0; }
}
class C extends B{}
```

I add a contrived, legal constructor to the `Contrived` class, taking a `List<? extends T>`:

```
public Contrived(List<? extends T> values)
{
   this.values = values;
}
```

This allows me to write a `main` method such as the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   List<C> bList = Arrays.asList(new C(), new C(), new C());
   Contrived<B> ci = new Contrived<B>(bList);
}
```

I can pass a `List<C>` into the constructor for a `Contrived<B>`.

Another design for the contrived constructor that is legal for `Contrived` could be, taking a `List<T>`:

```
public Contrived(List<T> values)
{
   this.values = values;
}
```

Such a constructor doesn't allow a `List<C>` for a `Contrived<B>`, because now the types must match, as in the following two `Contrived` examples:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   List<C> cList = Arrays.asList(new C(), new C(), new C());
   Contrived<C> ci = new Contrived<C>(cList);  // must match now
}
```

And

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   List<B> bList = Arrays.asList(new B(), new B(), new B());
   Contrived<B> ci = new Contrived<B>(bList);  // must match now
}
```

Comment: As long as we are talking contrived, you can also assign `this` to `values`.

Comment: @Radiodef Confirmed, your contrived example, `this.values = this;`, is legal inside either of my contrived `Contrived` constructors.

Comment: could be have both constructors in case of overloading;but that would not make sense in this case I suppose; since the first one is a relaxed version of the latter restricted one..?

Comment: @user1988876 Well actually you can't have both since they have the same erasure. They are just two different examples.